# no viable alternative at character ' ' error in the function

Tags: pine-script

I am trying to create a function for the candlesticks. However, I get the following error:
*line 18: no viable alternative at character ' '*. Do you have any idea of how this error could be fixed? Please see below the script. Thank you for your help.

```
//@version=5
indicator(title="Function error compile test1", overlay=true)

plot(close)


f_find_candles(float candle0bot, float candle0up, float candle1bot, float candle1up)=>
    var float a = na
    var float b = na
    var float c = na
    var float d = na
    var float e = na
    var float f = na

    if (candle1bot > candle0bot) and (candle1up > candle0up) and (candle1bot > candle0up)
        a := candle0bot
        b := candle0up
        c := candle1bot
        d := candle1up 
    else if candle1bot > candle0bot and candle1bot < candle0up and candle1up > candle0up
        e := candle0bot
        f := candle1up
    else
        na
    [a, b, c, d, e, f]
```

Comment: This code compiles just fine.

Comment: There was an indentation problem, I was able to fix it.

Comment: Your should post an answer showing where the indentation error was. It may serve to help others. Or was your edit to the question, where you added indentation, the actual fix?